# Could the "abusive to others" message template be revised to include a link to the Be Nice page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, moderator-messages, moderator-templates

We've got a great [Be Nice policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), and when a user runs afoul of it, it seems like a good idea to point them in the direction of that page.

However, the current candidate moderator message template doesn't do that.

Could it be revised to include a pointer to this page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been completed and will be out in the next deploy.